Http trigger in Azure functions application
I have an Azure functions application performing background jobs for my web site. Some jobs are started on demand. To achieve that I use a single HTTP trigger function calling it from web server, providing job details. The function starts a corresponding orchestration and returns a check status response.
In simplified form, that launcher function looks like this:
[FunctionName(nameof(StartJob))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> StartJob(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    HttpContent? content = req.Content ?? throw new Exception("Request body missing");
    string requestBody = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    dynamic jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody) ?? throw new Exception("No data");

    int requestId = (int)jObject.RequestId;

    // read the task description from DB
    var task = await ServerTaskHelper.GetTaskAsync(_connectionHelper, requestId);

    // start executing
    var oid = await starter.StartNewAsync(task.OrchestratorFunction);
    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, oid);
}

It works well in test environment, but in production, some requests fail. Unfortunately I do not know the response code: there is no appropriate logging for now. But I think it could be due to big number of requests.
My question: is it a good approach to start jobs on demand? How many requests can an Azure Function app handle? Maybe it is better to put requests into a queue on the web server, and make a queue trigger in Azure?
The runtime version of my Azure application is 4.28.4.4 targeting .NET 6.0, with "in-process" model. Pricing plan is "Premium v3 P1V3".
Thank you in advance!

Can you provide the function that has failed requests? Usually there shouldnt be a scaling issue. Maybe you have set limits to the instances of a function? However, I would advise against using HTTP Triggers for on demand functions. There should be a better trigger for your need (queue or whatever).

@Aaron I've added a code example. It is very simple and includes only one database operation. It could be a little bit faster if I move reading of task description from the trigger to orchestration, but I'm not sure whether it makes sense. I'm also thinking about putting requests in Azure queue instead of calling the Http trigger: in the theory it should use all the scalability of Azure platform and be much faster and stable. But it will take time to change everything...

In certain situation it is true the by demand is a right approach by demand. If the volume is high and need an 100 % transaction success, then a queue is better approach.
Also, you are using Durable function, so there will be a storage account which store the state of the function, I request you review those tables you may identify the issue.
Also verify if the Azure function always on is turned on Azure function (How do I turn on "always-on" for an Azure Function?)

My application already is in "always-on" mode.
